# Python read numerical blocks (separated by single line of text) from text file into Numpy array or Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following 2 text files and they contain blocks of numbers separated by lines of text. I am trying to read the blocks into a Pandas dataframe or into a Numpy array. Here are the files:

**File1.txt:**

```
Line one text
Line two text
Line three text
Temperature Readings:  1   5   abcd
 17 7.7
 18 1.9
 19 14.6
 11 7.1
  4 2.4
Temperature Readings:  2   3   ddef
 26 4.2
 45 12.0
  2 9.3
Air-Pressure was taken:   17.0  474.0

Top Total
11    317
14     34
```

**File2.txt:**

```
Line one text
Line two text
Line three text
Temperature Readings:  1   3   fnlksn
 11 8.9
 35 2.6
 41 1.7
 14 3.3
  8 11.5
Temperature Readings:  2   7   vsfgfs
 16 26.7
 91 10.5
 12 11.3
Temperature Readings:  3   4   tomt_2
 11 11.2
 78 2.8
 56 1.5
Air-Pressure was taken:   17.0  474.0

Top Total
74     31
99     14
83     04
 9     10
```

I am looking for a way to read in both files. The problem is that in the first file, there are only 2 blocks of Temperature Readings. The second file has a different number of blocks - it is 3 in this example, but it could be any number.

This is what is causing me problems:

- I would like to read in the numbers below each block heading. I would
  like to read these numbers into a numpy array or pandas dataframe.
- The second problem I am having is that I do not know how to read in
  the numbers sinec they have a leading whitespace - this is making it
  difficult to separate them.

Here is what I would like to get:

From File1.txt:
t_1 =

```
   0    1
0 17  7.7
1 18  1.9
3 19 14.6
4  4  2.4
```

t_2 =

```
   0    1
0 26  4.2
1 45 12.0
2  2  9.3
```

From File2.txt:
t_1 =

```
   0    1
0 11  8.9
1 35  2.6
2 41  1.7
3 14  3.3
4  8 11.5
```

t_2 =

```
   0    1
0 16 26.7
1 91 10.5
2 12 11.3
```

t_3 =

```
   0    1
0 11 11.2
1 78  2.8
2 56  1.5
```

Is there a way to do this in Python 2.7?

EDIT: The lines including `Air-Pressure`, and below, can be ignored.

Comment: Look into the string methods `strip()` and `split()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it all in pandas or not but you can use `groupby` and `itertools.islice` to skip and group the lines:

```
from itertools import groupby,islice
import pandas as pd

with open("file2.txt") as f:
    for k, v in groupby(islice(f, 3, None),key=lambda x:  x.strip()[0:1].isdigit()):
        val = list(v)
        if k:
            df = pd.DataFrame(map(str.split,val))
            print(df)
            print(""))
        elif val[-1] == 'Top Total\n':
            break

    0     1
0  11   8.9
1  35   2.6
2  41   1.7
3  14   3.3
4   8  11.5

    0     1
0  16  26.7
1  91  10.5
2  12  11.3

    0     1
0  11  11.2
1  78   2.8
2  56   1.5
```

They are all actually  different datafames, how you store them is up to  you:

```
data_frames = []
with open("file2.txt") as f:
        for k, v in groupby(islice(f, 3, None),key=lambda x:  x.strip()[0:1].isdigit()):
            val = list(v)
            if k:
                data_frames.append(pd.DataFrame(map(str.split,val)))
            elif val[-1] == 'Top Total\n':
                break
print(data_frames) # three dataframes in a list
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I had to edit the original post. It is done now. Basically, at the end of the last numerical block in each file, there is one line, followed by a blank line and some numbers below it <-- this all needs to be ignored. Again, sorry for not including this in the OP. With this in mind, is it possible to say something like `.startswith("Air-Pressure| |Top")`?

Comment: @WR. are the lines containing digits all in the relevant data?

Comment: The edit has nearly worked, but they are all showing up in one DataFrame.i.e. what I have shown above as `t_1`, `t_2` and `t_3` are all showing up vertically concatenated as one DataFrame separated by a blank line (as per `print("")`). Is it possible to split these up into separate DataFrames by searching for the blank line and somehow using that as a way to separate them?

Comment: They are all different dataframes, I just printed them as I had no idea what you want to do with them

Comment: Is there a way for me to access them separately like `print df[0]`, `print df[1]`, etc.

Comment: `print(data_frames[0])`... Or store them in dicts and access by key

Comment: Got it. Didn't see your edit. Done. This solution has gone way beyond what I needed - it even provides the information after the `Air-Pressure` line. It also explicitly shows how to create a list of Pandas DataFrames. Great solution and many thanks!

Comment: No prob, glad it helped.

Comment: In your post with the response to the OP, could you explain what the `for` statement is doing?

Comment: @WR, it is starting at the third line of the file using islice then grouping sections of lines that start with digits, lines that don't start with digits are basically the delimiters